# Junit 4 checkbox in jmeter getting cleared when running test

Tags: jmeter, junit

I wrote a junit 4 test case. The test is using selenium web driver. It works fine when running from eclipse. I then copied the exported jar file to jmeter lib/junit folder. The class name and test name is populating when I am selecting **Search for Junit 4 annotations** checkbox. You can find this from screenshot.

[image]

But as soon as I start load test by clicking the green play button, the **Search for Junit 4 annotations** checkbox gets cleared and thereby no class and test name is passed to the load test. Please guide me.

Comment: i also faced the same issue i reinstalled the fresh copy of jmeter with required plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I see the same with version 2.13, I actually tried 2.11 and the checkbox is not being cleared. Try downloading version 2.11 from https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/ (haven't tried 2.12)

Comment: In my opinion this should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something is wrong with your setup, for instance you didn't copy Selenium libraries to JMeter's classpath (/lib folder of your JMeter installation). JMeter does not "discard" JUnit4 checkbox, moreover if you save your file and reopen it - it will persist. So check *jmeter.log* file for any warnings and errors and resolve them.

By the way, there is a [WebDriver Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) plugin which provides Selenium integration via custom sampler so you won't need to recompile/replace the jar if you need to update something.